# why do I get a 'returning address of local temporary' warning with std::bind()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, stl

I am trying to bind the key of a tree to a function, using a standard piece of code (Josuttis),
but Visual Studio 2010 warns (and crashes when I run it):

.../functional(447): warning C4172: returning address of local temporary

the code is:

```
void print(int x) { ... }

using namespace std;

map<int, float>  m;
for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), 
         bind( print,
               bind( &map<int,float>::value_type::first, placeholders::_1) ) );
```

this code seems to be working in other compilers fine.

Is there anything hidden inside the windows implementation of bind that causes this error?

Comment: A lambda might be easier: `[](map<int,float>::value_type pair){print(pair.first);}`

Comment: vs2012 says error C2780: 'enable_if<!std::is_same<_Ty1,_Ty2>::value,std::_Bind<true,_Ret,std::_Pmf_wrap<_Rx(__thiscall _Farg0::* )(_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t) volatile const,_Rx,_Farg0,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t>,_Vx0_t,_Vx1_t,_Vx2_t,_Vx3_t,_Vx4_t>>::type std::bind(_Rx (__thiscall _Farg0::* const )(_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t) volatile const,_Vx0_t &&,_Vx1_t &&,_Vx2_t &&,_Vx3_t &&,_Vx4_t &&)' : expects 6 arguments - 2 provided. What other compilers have you used?

Comment: @doctorlove I used vs2010. So, what's wrong with vs2012 ? This code should compile well !

Comment: @GrimFandango, I'm baffled. I'll report back if I figure this out

Comment: When calling bind the 1st parameter should be a function pointer.  In your second call to bind you're not passing a function pointer.  (I have **absolutely** no clue what you ARE passing!)

Comment: @user1158692 no, first argument to `std::bind` can also be a pointer to member. Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/?kw=bind

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
&map<int,float>::value_type::first
```

use:

```
&m::value_type::first
```

all though it shouldn't make a difference, that way you're not using a local temporary.

Comment: How would that make a difference? You're trying to form a pointer to member.

Comment: nope, this is a compiler error: `error C2510: 'm' : left of '::' must be a class/struct/union`